# Need to stop SteamVR camera seeing through walls

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, steam, htc-vive

I am using player prefab from SteamVR Plugin. Whenever player touches an object with a Collider on it, camera sees through it. I am using 0.01 as minimum clipping value. I have also added Rigidbody and Collider on camera.

Comment: your camera has a minimum render distance, the near plane. you´d need to stop your object before that to stop looking through it. maybe encapsulate your camera in anoter collider, that is further from the camera than the near plane

Comment: I have tried it already. This doesn't seems to work for me.

Comment: If i stop my camera object from entering in wall mesh, its collider stays out but in headset view, it is entering inside wall.

Comment: Well then you might consider implementing something like Crytek does in The Climb where the screen turns black if you stick your head into a wall.

Comment: I currently don´t have the time looking into this myself so I can´t really help you with this. Also the downvote is not mine.

Comment: Well thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also do not have code currently but here’s a concept of how to approach the problem:

1. Keep a trigger collider on the camera.
2. Write a script that detects when that collider is within another collider (your walls). There is a method for checking if colliders are intersecting/overlapping
3. If there is an intersect/overlap, fade the camera to black. If there is not, fade back.

Comment: Awesome! Way to go!